# how to use different conditions in a ruby hash select

Tags: ruby

I am trying to select a subset of a hash.
Suppose I have a method which does this, e.g.,

```
def create_html (entities, low, high)
  entities
    .select{|k,v| v[:entity_count] < low and v[:community] == true}
    .sort_by{| k,v| v[:count]}.each do | k,v |
.....
```

I want to handle various conditions:
assume a lower limit (low) and higher limit (high)

1. count < low
2. count > low and count < high
3. count > high

I also want to use lte and gte. Is there an easy way to handle all the combinations in my select statement? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. You want to handle all these conditions within the same select?

Comment: I want to create different kinds of reports.  In some cases I want items below the low threshold.  In other cases, anything greater than low and less than high.

Comment: Are these reports coming from an SQL database?

Comment: @SrdjanPejic I create a hash.  I then select a subset and create a html report.  The report will contain - top entities, middle entities, and low entities.  Hope that explains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you are trying to do. But you could just use a block to extract the condition.

```
def create_html (entities)
  entities
    .select{|k,v| yield(v[:entity_count], v[:community]) }
    .sort_by{| k,v| v[:count]}.each do | k,v |
.....
```

And then you could have all your conditions based on that field.

```
create_html(entities) { |count| count < low }
create_html(entities) { |count| count > low && count < high }
create_html(entities) { |count| count < low }

# Also with community == true
create_html(entities) { |count, community| count < low && community }
```

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for.  Could you tell me how to do this if I want to handle another condition in the same way, e.g., the v[:community] == true.  Suppose I want to choose true or false.  Can I use 2 yields?

Comment: you can, bu what you want is to pass the `v[:community]` inside the same yeild. I will update my answer